# Mongodb c++ driver: how to query for an Array for an Element

Tags: c++, arrays, mongodb

[The document for using the c++ mongodb driver](http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3) is very lacking compared to [the js document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/).

However, the syntax of the c++ driver often has one-to-one mapping to the js syntax. So in case something is undocumented regarding using the c++ driver, mimicking the js code often works.

But for the following task ([found on the js document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/)), I wasn't able to find the right c++ solution:

> **Query an Array for an Element**
>   To query if the array field contains at
>   least one element with the specified value, use the filter { :
>    } where  is the element value.
>
> The following example queries for all documents where tags is an array
>   that contains the string "red" as one of its elements:
>
> ```
> db.inventory.find( { tags: "red" } )
> ```

My current code:

```
mongocxx::cursor cursor = 
inventoryCollection.find(bsoncxx::builder::stream::document{}
            << "tags" << "red"
            << bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_document
            << bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize);
```

This will cause an exception. Apparently for an Array Field, it is not allowed to give it a String as a search query:  **"tags" << "red"**

How should I achieve this in c++?

Comment: What is the error being thrown? MongoDB itself does not care if the property in the query is a string or array of strings, so that's not the issue here. The `close_document` is not really needed in the builder here either, and for "code clarity" I would suggest not constructing such statements "inline" to the function call

Answer (score 0):

I think you are double closing the stream. Eliminate the call to `stream::close_document` and just let `stream::finalize` do it for you.